# windows function + partition hard

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, function, partition

i need to do same result but not with join But rather windows function + partition.
the output is the year, customer id and the ratio of customer proit to the all profit in a year.

```
year    Customer_ID    ratio          
2012    2              0.0222
2012    4              0.049
2012    37             0.015
2013    2              0.124


this is the join that work


SELECT a.year, a.Customer_ID, a.profit/b.profit as ratio 
FROM (  select year(order_date) as year, Customer_ID, sum(Profit) as profit 
        from [targil 2].[dbo].[exc2 - orders] 
        group by year(order_date) , Customer_ID
        ) A 
CROSS JOIN (select year(order_date) as year, sum(Profit) as profit
            from [targil 2].[dbo].[exc2 - orders]
            group by year(order_date)) B 
            where a.year = b.year;
```

Comment: You've made a statement, shown us your sample data and then showed us a failed attempt, but you haven't asked a question or shown us the result set you're after. We can't help you if we don't have a question and a goal to aim for. What is your question here? How can we help you?

Comment: Your sample data just doesn't make sense.  There is one customer is 2013, so by your description, the ratio should be 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult without sample data, but if you want to use a statement without `CROSS JOIN` and using window function, next statement may help:

```
SELECT 
    a.[year], 
    a.Customer_ID, 
    a.profit / SUM(a.profit) OVER (PARTITION BY a.[year]) as ratio 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        YEAR(order_date) as [year], 
        Customer_ID, 
        SUM(Profit) as profit 
    FROM [targil 2].[dbo].[exc2 - orders] 
    GROUP BY YEAR(order_date), Customer_ID
) a
```

Notes:

- If `profit` is an `int` column, you'll need an additional `CONVERT`.
- Documentation  about [SUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function states, that *" .. order_by_clause is required ..."*, so using `SUM ... OVER ...` like this is more close to the books: `SUM(profit) OVER (PARTITION BY [year] ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))`.